# how to set configurations variables and access it in rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a set of parameters that needs to be initialized for elasticMQ sqs. Right now I have added in the controller as below.

```
sqs = RightAws::SqsGen2.new("ABCD","DEFG",{:server=>"localhost",:port=>9324,:protocol=>"http"})
```

what is the better way to set it in config folder and access it in controller and how to do it. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a config file **config/config.yml** that will store the config variables for the different environments and load it in config/application.rb.

```
development:
  elasticmq:
    server: localhost
    port: 9324
    protocol: 'http'

production:
  elasticmq:
    server:
    port:
    protocol:

test:
```

In config/application.rb:

```
CONFIG = YAML.load_file("config/config.yml")[Rails.env]
```

The CONFIG variable is now available in the controller.So now you can do the following:

```
sqs = RightAws::SqsGen2.new("ABCD","DEFG",{:server=>"#{CONFIG['elasticmq']['server']}",:port=> "#{CONFIG['elasticmq']['port']}",:protocol=>"#{CONFIG['elasticmq']['protocol']}"})
```